# How do you call SSRS Soap from inside an SSIS Package?

Tags: reporting-services, ssis

I'm processing data coming from SQL Server which I will convert to a text file then upload to SSRS folder.

I tried using web service task component but it fails.

Any idea how I can go about the problem?

Comment: Your title does seem to match the detail of your question. Are you trying to push a data file to a Sharepoint report library?

Comment: Yes I have a batch file which create a text file, this text file should be uploaded to SSRS via soap or rest, i tried using the Web Service Task but it does not work, so I'm thinking of using script task instead.

Comment: a SOAP mesage is typically used to request data from a web service. If that is the case you can use a webclient inside script task and use UpLoadFile method

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was doing now will publish the solution once done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here's the code in the script task and how you can connect to SSRS and upload the file. Here is a method that accepts a byte array and uploads to SSRS using default credential used to run the ssis package, which of course should also have access to ssrs or a specific folder in ssrs where you intend to upload the file.

```
protected bool UploadFile(byte[] data, string description)
    {


        var result = false;
        try
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                var fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}{3}.zip", ZipPrefix, TargetDate, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"));
                var prefix = string.Format("{0}_{1}", ZipPrefix, TargetDate);

                ServiceManager.ReportingService2010 rs = new ServiceManager.ReportingService2010
                {
                    Url = ServiceUrl,
                    RequestEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                };

                rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                ServiceManager.Property[] properties = {
                    new ServiceManager.Property() { Name = "MimeType", Value = "application/zip" }
                    ,new ServiceManager.Property(){ Name ="Description", Value = description}
                };

                var listItems = rs.ListChildren(SSRSFolder, false);

                //var a = string.Join(", ", listItems.Select(x => x.Name));
                //MessageBox.Show(a);

                foreach (var item in listItems)
                {
                    if (item.Name.Contains(prefix))
                    {
                        rs.DeleteItem(item.Path);
                    }
                }

                rs.CreateCatalogItem("Resource", fileName, SSRSFolder, false, data, properties, out ServiceManager.Warning[] warnings);

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = string.Format("Upload Error : {0}", e.Message);

            Dts.Log(e.Message, 1, null);
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
```

Please note that we need to add a Service Reference to the SSRS Soap.